# How to fix this code, i'm not getting error but data are not exported to csv

Tags: scala, csv, jdbc, load-testing, gatling

I'm creating a load testing and i need to get data from database, so i created another file in gatling to get data from db and export it to csv file, to use the file as a feeder later, the exporting to csv isn't working

```
import java.io._

import com.github.tototoshi.csv._
import io.gatling.core.Predef._
import io.gatling.core.feeder.SourceFeederBuilder
import io.gatling.jdbc.Predef._

import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer

class GenerateData extends Simulation {

  val csvFileLocation = new File("data.csv")
  val writers: CSVWriter = CSVWriter.open(csvFileLocation)

  // load and register JDBC driver for MySQL
  Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver")

  // DATABASE
  val dbStatement: String = System.getProperty("dbStatement", "SELECT * FROM db limit 1")
  val dbQuery: SourceFeederBuilder[Any] = jdbcFeeder("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/table?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC", "username", "pass", dbStatement)
//
  var recordCount: Int = dbQuery.readRecords.length
  var mList = new Array[String](recordCount)
  var dataString: ArrayBuffer[String] = ArrayBuffer[String]()
  var dataCounts: ArrayBuffer[Int] = ArrayBuffer[Int]()
  val out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(csvFileLocation))
  val writer = new CSVWriter(out)

  val scn = scenario("Database Query")
    .feed(dbQuery)
    writer.writeRow(dataString)
    writer.close()

  setUp(scn.inject(atOnceUsers(1)))
}
```

Nothing is added to csv file and i'm only getting error about reporting from gatling

could you please help

Comment: If you print recordCount, are there actually any records returned? Also, are you meaning to put the recordCount (an Int) in mList (an Array of Strings)?

Answer (score 1):

You do:

```
var dataString: ArrayBuffer[String] = ArrayBuffer[String]()
writer.writeRow(dataString)
```

`dataString` is always empty, you're not overwriting `dataString`

Answer (score 0):

I think your

`writer.writeRow(dataString)
 writer.close()`

lines would also need to be in a proper gatling dsl step too?

so...

```
val scn = scenario("Database Query")
.feed(dbQuery)
.exec(session -> {
    //code to add the value from you dbQuery feeder to dataString 
    writer.writeRow(dataString)
    writer.close()
    session
})
```